Can a bad outdoor A/C compressor unit or other inline component fail to return power to a furnace?
We have a forced air HVAC system: gas furnace in the basement for heat and an A/C unit outside for cooling. There is a pull-out style shutoff plug that is wired from the breaker panel to the A/C and then to the furnace...in that order. Shutoff plug was installed by professionals when furnace was new like 8 years ago. There also is an emergency shut off switch wired in somewhere that is at top of basement stairs. Outdoor A/C unit has its own pull out shut off. This is a 2 zone system; 2 thermostats one upstairs in bedroom one down on floor level.
So the A/C stopped working in late summer after severe t-storms; we got some water in the basement but the furnace did not get wet. Found no power coming into the furnace wire according to a Volt pen but there was juice in the wire coming from the breaker and into the A/C. Found old brittle black wire leads broken inside the outlet/switch box that is wired to the furnace and a ground wire appears to have come uncapped from the other copper ground wires. That green wire may have popped off when the faceplate was pulled out to look at it. Also found the condensation sump pump was full and clogged. Cleaned everything out and reattached pvc drain pipe to find the plug outlet that powers sump pump only has 30 volts instead of the 120v that it should. There is no float switch attached to the condensation pump sump unit but the unit does have wires coming out of the pump for this purpose. A rusty 120v to 24v transformer was wired/attached to the outlet/switch. Zero voltage to furnace, control boards, dampers, or thermostat.
First we replaced the 120v/24v transformer. Ran a new wire from the shutoff plug box to the furnace. Wired a new outlet and switch in the same way as it was before and attached the new transformer. Attached the 24v C and R wires to the transformer which was already wired to the furnace control board and zone controller. Replaced a bad capacitor on side of A/C unit. Found the AC contactor had A spider nest in it but tested ok; replaced it anyway.
Reset the breaker and shutoffs. Voltage pen beeped red- was now showing power to the furnace. Flipped on the switch to the furnace and set the thermostat to call for heat. Furnace seemed to initiate sequence of operation, leds on control boards and dampers lit, but furnace just quit. Pen showed no power to the furnace wire again. Seems like something is tripping off at the A/C each time which kills power to furnace wire. Can a bad outdoor A/C compressor unit or other inline component fail to return power to a furnace?

Why is the AC coming on when you are calling for heat?

Welcome to DIY.SE! A few things to help your question: 1. The wall of text needs formatting: Paragraphs, bullets for what things have been done, etc. 2. Clarify: "There is a pull-out style shutoff plug that is wired from the breaker panel to the A/C and then to the furnace...in that order" Where in the order is the pullout? 3. Clarify: "Outdoor A/C unit has its own pull out shut off." Is this the same A/C as the A/C in point 2? 4. How many circuit breakers feed this furnace and A/C's? Add pictures, please.

Had HVAC pro look at my system. I had to bypass the AC completely in order to get power to the furnace. Turns out nothing is wrong with the furnace itself but there is a problem with my AC unit and/or 220v system that delivers power to the AC unit.

Rewired from the box to the furnace; found an outlet and some old wring was bad. That may have been related but was not the source of issue here. May have been a power surge during/after the storm which damaged an AC component or something else in the 220v system that delivers the power to the AC. So the short answer to my own Q is yes.... failure in a 220v system that is connected to a furnace can fail to deliver power if on the same circuit.
